# Using Scope in Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, kaminari

I'm trying to use Kaminari to paginate a model. However, I'm using scope in my model which throws some error.

```
undefined method `to_sym' for 1:Fixnum
```

My scope:

```
scope :my_scope, select('DISTINCT(rank), COUNT(rank) no_rank').group(1).order('2 DESC')
```

In my controller:

```
@users = User.my_scope.page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

Changed my scope to:

```
scope :my_scope, select('DISTINCT(rank), COUNT(rank) no_rank').group('rank')
```

and in my controller

```
@users = User.my_scope.order('rank DESC').page(params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `@users = User.my_scope.all.page(params[:page])` or something?  Actually, wouldn't group 1 return one record and you wouldn't have to paginate it?  Is this the real query?

Comment: I think all is not appropriate based on the kaminari wiki.